# How do I programmatically change the constraint to a branch in ClearCase?

Tags: constraints, branch, clearcase

We have several branches that were set to one per branch and we want to change those to one per element.
I cannot seem to find an example of that command.

I can do it with the windows and xclearcase but that is one at a time and I want to do the whole VOB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the branch label type.

That is actually done with [`cleartool mkbrtype -replace`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbrtype.htm?cp=SSSH27_9.0.0%2F11-0-0-1-35&lang=en) (ClearCase 7, 8 and 9.x): you are replacing an existing branch type with a new one.

```
cleartool mkbrtype -replace -pbranch -c "my branch bis" mybranch@/vobs/myvob
```

> By default only one branch of this type can be created in an element's entire version tree.
>   The `-pbranch` option loosens this constraint.